# Gnome Nautilus - How to add directory to the index so it can be "starred"

Tags: gnome, nautilus, indexing

I'm trying to take advantage of the starring option in [Nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Files). But it seems like there is a [Bug which doesn't allow to "star" no indexed directories](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/243).

**How do I add a directory to the index?**

[image: screenshot "stared" directories]

**Note 1:** right now it seems like I can only star directories in the first level of the Users folder as well as in the default folders like Desktop, Documents, Downloads etc. 
**Note 2:** [the way starring how it worked in Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148262/) seems not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus uses [Tracker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Tracker) to index the files in the system. We can use `tracker` command to add new files or directory.

```
tracker index --help

NAME
       tracker-index - List, pause, resume and command data miners indexing content

SYNOPSIS
       tracker index --reindex-mime-type <mime1> [[-m [mime2]] ...]
       tracker index --file <file1> [[file2] ...]
       tracker index --import <file1> [[file2] ...]
       tracker index --backup <file> | --restore <file>
```

Check current indexed folders and files:

```bsh
tracker status

Currently indexed: 373 files, 49 folders
Remaining space on database partition: 234.0 GB (55.50%)
All data miners are idle, indexing complete
```

For instance if you want to index this additional folder `/home/user/newfolder`

```bsh
tracker index --file /home/user/newfolder

# Confirm that the new folder has been indexed.
# Should output more files and folders than before.
tracker status
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The only thing missing was to restart (or close all) Nautilus windows!

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.10, the command to add a directory, and its sub-directories, is...

$ tracker3 index --add --recursive Dir

...where Dir is the path to your directory.

To list the directories being indexed, use...

$ tracker3 index

More information...
$ info tracker3-index