# Often can't "Star" a file. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pdf

I often want to "Star" a file for quick opening. Sometimes it works and often it doesn't. The type of file doesn't matter; sometimes I can but often not. PDF, jpeg, text file, it doesn't matter. Tonight I starred a PDF file and wanted to star two others. The first one worked, the other two did not. I encounter this all the time. Sometimes after a reboot they will. It's a major annoyance for me.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148278/1222991) will explain why some files cannot be starred and how you can resolve the issue 

Comment: All of that has been set long ago. After a reboot I can star but after running for a while I often can't.

Comment: If this is something that can be repeated, then it could be a bug in Nautilus. If this is the case, being able to outline the steps to reproduce the issue and [reporting it as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en) could go a long way to helping others who may have that same issue 